# Every method should start with the same thing

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, startup

I'm working with an interface, handling incoming messages.
The definition of that interface looks as follows:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<TMessage> where TMessage : ...
{
    void Handle(TMessage message);
}
```

This interface is defined in a DLL.
I don't have the possibility to modify that DLL.

I have different classes, all looking like this:

```
public class GeneralManager:
IMessageHandler<GetStockMessage>,
IMessageHandler<GetLocationMessage>,
IMessageHandler<GetDetailsMessage>,
...
public class SpecificManager:
IMessageHandler<GetListMessage>,
IMessageHandler<GetPositonsMessage>,
...
```

As you can imagine, for each of those messages I have a handler in its manager class, something like:

```
public void Handle(GetStockMessage message) { ... }
public void Handle(GetLocationMessage message) { ... }
public void Handle(GetDetailsMessage message) { ... }
```

I would like every of those `Handle()` methods to start with the following line:

```
log.Debug($"Handling [{message.GetType().Name}]");
```

As there are not less than 149 of those `Handle()` methods, I would prefer not needing to do "copy/paste" everywhere :-)

Is this possible without modifying the DLL, containing the definition of the interface? If yes, how? (In case it's not possible I please also put the solution. I won't be able to implement it here but it might be interesting for later purposes)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to use a decorator, such as Injecting Behaviors Before and After Method Execution 
[Read More Here](https://doc.postsharp.net/custompatterns/aspects/tutorials/method-decorator)

Comment: `where TMessage : string`  really a type constraint on string?

Comment: [Fody is a good free tool for code injection](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) that you can use to do this.

Comment: You can't even constrain a type to `string` - you'll get a compile error (because `string` is `sealed`).

Comment: Actually all the tools for method decoration that I'm aware of require you to add an attribute to each method that's being decorated, so they won't help you avoid having to write *any* additional code.

Comment: This question is answerable if this is a typo: `where TMessage : string`. `string` is a sealed type. Nothing inherits from it. So this wouldn't make any sense as a generic interface. `message` would always be a string. This wouldn't compile. I'm guessing it's not a string - it's some other type of interface. In that case there's a simple answer, but I don't want to answer unless I correctly understand the question.

Comment: Guys, I would like to apologise for the misunderstanding: when putting pieces of code on the site, I do some modifications for copyright purposes. As such I have replaced the name of a base class by `string` (believing that this would not make a difference), but that clearly was a mistake. I've replaced `string` by `...`, meaning that this is not the issue I'm dealing with here.

Answer (score 2):

3 methods I can think of:

1. Use an IL weaver like Fody.
2. Write a source generator that generate the Handle methods.
3. Create a helper `MessageHandler<TMessage> : IMessageHandler<TMessage>` that does the logging and delegates to the real hander

Option 3 is probably the easiest (depending on your application structure), but I'm not sure it beats just taking 10 minutes and copy/paste the `log.Debug` calls (or create a method `Log(object message) => log.Debug($"Handling [{message.GetType().Name}]");` and call that).

Comment: I believe the third option being the best as well but I have no idea how to program this.